# How to send source code to vagrant virtual machine?

Tags: chef, vagrant

I am looking for a way to start a virtual machine using my chef recipes that would deploy my application. The deployment works fine with a git repository, but the problem is that I would have to push my code everytime I want to test it on my chef managed environment.

Therefore, I created a symlink from my project to the /files/default/ folder of my cookbook, and use this folder as the directory of my project (instead of the git repository). The problem is that there are like 40,000 files and the `kitchen converge` command takes forever.

Is there a better way? The goal is to work on my code, and then deploy it as quick as possible on the virtual machine to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using kitchen's vagrant driver?  if yes, you might have better luck using it's [Synced Folders](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/) feature which is realized through the [synced_folder kitchen config](https://docs.chef.io/config_yml_kitchen.html#kitchen-vagrant) like so:

```
platforms:
  - name: default
    driver:
      box: bento/centos-7.2
      customize:
        memory: 8192
      synced_folders:
        - ["path/to/code/on/host", "/host-code"]
```

This should make /host-code be available to your guest in real time.  Definitely avoid stashing large files in your cookbooks - it bogs all kinds of things down.  We use this type of approach with synced folders all the time.  You can compile/build apps on your host as well as edit other surrounding stuff, and use chef node attributes specified in your kitchen file to override the cookbook behavior to load from local paths on the guest that are synced with the host.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

> The deployment works fine with a git repository, but the problem is
>   that I would have to push my code everytime I want to test it on my
>   chef managed environment.

This seems to me to be a feature, not a bug. Deploying from commits ensures nothing is left behind in the working copy. If you cannot alter the current branch, make a new branch.

Or, consider building and deploying package management archives. Installing an archive is fairly fast, and you will have a deliverable nearly ready to install for users.

Although, you may not achieve the speeds git did at syncing tens of thousands of files, which is it very good at.